# Receive massive post request on server

Tags: c#, iis, web, request

hi i am new to the web design. i am currently facing an issue from my program. My program will run at the server and it will dynamically create a lot of aspx pages with short script to store the post request data at run time . However, when there's a lot of post request receive in a short time, there's some pages become blank and the data didn't store in the page. Is there any better way to handle massive post request so that i can guarantee receive the post request data? Thank you

Page Code: i believe this is the issue

this is code where every aspx page contain

```
<script runat="server" language=`enter code here`"C#">
    public static string IDValue;
    public static string incomeData;
    void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    incomeData = Request["RequestID"];
    if (incomeData != null && incomeData != ""){
        IDValue = incomeData ;
    }
    Response.Write(IDValue);
    }
```

This page is just basicly store the RequestID on the page so that i can retrieve the RequestID in the future. It does work for most case, but sometimes there's 1 or 2 pages didn't write on the page.

Comment: this is code where every aspx page contain

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you are generating aspx pages on disk to store data?!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should remove the static keyword.

When using static keyword there will only be one instance of the value, and in your case it could easily be overwritten by another request that occuired at the same time.

Your code should look like this:

```
public string IDValue;  // If not referenced in the HTML, it should be moved inside the Page_Load method.
void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string incomeData = Request["RequestID"];
    if (incomeData != null && incomeData != "")
    {
        IDValue = incomeData ;
    }
    Response.Write(IDValue);
}
```

Hope this will help you with your quest.